# Possible dismissals off a noball, wide ball and free hit

Tags: rules, cricket, officiating, icc

I came to know that a batsman can be stumped out off a wide ball but not off a no-ball (Is it correct?)

What are the possibilities to dismiss batsmen, off a noball, a wide ball, a freehit ball and two or three pitched(dead)ball?

Comment: A Batsman can be out Stumped of a No Ball when he is using a Runner.

Comment: If a runner is 'stumped', then it is treated as a run-out and not stumped. Also, the use of runners have been banned by ICC from late 2011.

Comment: Orangecrush,
The Batsman can be stumped of a No Ball if using a runner. If the runner is out of the crease then that would be Run out. ICC uses Laws of Cricket in conjunction with Playing Regulations. The Playing Regulations do not allow runners.

Comment: Welcome to Sports SE! Would suggest you to go through the [FAQ section](http://sports.stackexchange.com/faq) before posting any further answers. Also, if you have any queries or want to point anything out related to the question/answer, please post a comment on your previous answer and do not post it as a separate answer. Thanks!

Comment: @Orangecrush Keep in mind that users with <50 rep cannot comment.

Comment: @PATELDAKU Welcome to Sports SE! Three things. 1) Creating multiple accounts are not recommended. 2) Multiple answers are also not recommended. 3) If you would like to clarify your answer, you have the ability to edit it.

Comment: @edmastermind29 Yes, I understand. What I meant was for him to comment on his first answer, as one doesnt need any rep to do so on ones own answer. Anyways, since that also was to be a comment, I don't see any other way out for him apart from editing the original answer.

Comment: A two- or three-pitched delivery is not a dead ball, it is a no-ball.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you are right when you say that a batsman can be stumped off a wide but not off a no-ball.

- No Ball dismissals - hitting the ball twice, obstructing the field and run out ([Law 21.8](https://www.lords.org/mcc/laws-of-cricket/laws/law-21-no-ball/)).
- Wide dismissals -  hit wicket, obstructing the field, run out and stumped. ([Law 22.9](https://www.lords.org/mcc/laws-of-cricket/laws/law-22-wide-ball/))
- Freehit dismissals - hitting the ball twice, obstructing the field and run out.

[Law 21.7](https://www.lords.org/mcc/laws-of-cricket/laws/law-21-no-ball/) states that,

> **Ball bouncing more than once or rolling along the ground**
>
> The umpire shall call and signal No ball if a ball which he/she considers to have been delivered, without having previously touched bat or person of the striker, bounces more than once or rolls along the ground before it reaches the popping crease

So, in such cases the delivery is considered a no-ball and the same rules of a no-ball apply.