# Can a batsman be out hit wicket on a wide or a no ball?

Tags: rules, cricket

A batsman tries to hit the ball on leg side and ball passes way away from the leg stump, no contact with ball and it passes by the stumps, after that the batsman touches the leg stumps by heels..
Will it be wide or batsman will be considered as out??

Comment: Your title refers to no balls, but your actual question makes no reference to no balls whatsoever. Could you clarify what you're actually asking about?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Possible dismissals off a noball, wide ball and free hit](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/1855/possible-dismissals-off-a-noball-wide-ball-and-free-hit)

Answer (score 3):

A batsman cannot be out hit wicket on a no ball; quoting from [Law 21.18](https://www.lords.org/mcc/laws-of-cricket/laws/law-21-no-ball/):

> When No ball has been called, neither batsman shall be out under any of the Laws except 34 (Hit the ball twice), 37 (Obstructing the field) or 38 (Run out).

However, a batsman *can* be out hit wicket from a wide; [Law 22.9](https://www.lords.org/mcc/laws-of-cricket/laws/law-22-wide-ball/):

> When Wide ball has been called, neither batsman shall be out under any of the Laws except **35 (Hit wicket)**, 37 (Obstructing the field), 38 (Run out) or 39 (Stumped).

(my emphasis).